# Basic TCL variable dereferencing in a loop

Tags: tcl

I have a loop that looks something like:

```
foreach x {a b} {
    set type_$x [some_function_here]
    set N_$x [function type_$x]
    }
```

The problem is that I want to dereference type_$a in the second line and use its value as the function argument.

However doing:

```
set N_$x [function $type_$x]
```

doesn't work and neither did any of the other combinations I tried with the subst command did either.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Three possibilities, in order of how much I think you should prefer them.

### Arrays

By far the easiest technique is to use an array instead:

```
foreach x {a b} {
    set type($x) [some_function_here]
    set N($x) [function $type($x)]
}
```

This does change how the rest of your program sees things, so it's not a zero-impact technique, but it's very easy; I think this is the most recommended way of doing this.

### Local Aliases

Alternatively, use `upvar 0` to make a local alias to the variable-named variable:

```
foreach x {a b} {
    upvar 0 type_$x typex N_$x Nx
    set typex [some_function_here]
    set Nx [function $typex]
}
```

Internally, the names just resolve to the same storage cell, so this is an efficient technique (though `upvar 0` is quite tricky!)

### Single-Argument `set`

Finally, you can read from an arbitrarily-named variable using the `set` command with *one* argument; the `$` syntax is arguably just syntactic sugar for that.

```
foreach x {a b} {
    set type_$x [some_function_here]
    set N_$x [function [set type_$x]]
}
```

It's usually something of a code-smell if you're doing that a lot, and it usually indicates that you should be using an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
set N_$x [function [set type_$x]]
```

The `$var` notation is basically shorthand for the command `[set var]`, and sometimes you need to use the command rather than the shorthand.

There is no way to tell the command evaluation "when I say '$type_$x' I want you to hold up evaluating the first `$` until the whole variable name has been put together". That is, unless you write it as `[set type_$x]`, in which case the name `type_a` or `type_b` is constructed first, and then passed to `set`.

Documentation: [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [evaluation syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Some others ways to do a deference of a variable with dynamic name.

```
% set x a
a
% set type_$a stackoverflow
stackoverflow
% expr \$type_$a
stackoverflow
% subst $[subst type_$a]
```

This is bit complex, comparable to other methods though.

Comment: Both techniques require runtime re-compilation, and are going to be slow. You might as well include `eval "string cat \$type_$a"` too, for the perfect group of techniques that are a Bad Idea…

Comment: @Donal Fellows : Anticipated about the slowness. Thanks for the information. One more learning today.